# Derivative of $\frac{d}{d\theta }\left(\left(\theta \:-1\right)\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\:\ln\left(x_i\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maximum-likelihood

I'm doing some maximum likelihood estimation exercise and I got stuck on the derivative of the following part: $\frac{d}{d\theta }\left(\left(\theta \:-1\right)\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\:\ln\left(x_i\right)\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is a constant with respect to $\theta$. So the answer is $$\sum\limits_{i}\ln x_i,$$ since $\frac{d}{d\theta}((\theta-1)c)=c$ if $c$ is a constant.

Comment: The sum notation makes it a little bit confusing, but replacing it with c makes a lot of sense!

Comment: See this:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31696/210401